# Select query on temp table without using cursor SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want perform SQL query on table schema

```
Id | BusNo | PartNo |dateAdded
1  | 437   | 2      |2014-02-28
2  | 423   | 3      |2014-03-28
3  | 423   | 3      |2014-04-28
4  | 437   | 2      |2014-03-28
5  | 452   | 1      |2014-03-29
```

I would like to select results top `ID` order by date with where condition on `BusNo` and `PartNo`.Result would be like this

```
Id | BusNo | PartNo |dateAdded
3  | 423   | 3      |2014-04-28
4  | 437   | 2      |2014-03-28
5  | 452   | 1      |2014-03-29
```

I tried

```
select [Id] 
into  
from [PartUsed] 
where BusNo = @busNo and [PartNo] exists (select ID from @Usertable)
```

`@userTable` is user defined table type, but it will select all rows and I want top 1 in `partNo` group order by `dateAdded`.

Comment: What's the @Usertable

Comment: @userTable is user defined table type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With cte as ( Select id,busno,partno,dateadded,
              Row_Number() over( partition by partno order by dateadded desc ) as seqNum
              from Partused
             )

select id,busno,partno,dateadded
from cte
where seqNum=1
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***P L E A S E*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s Aye Aye Captain !

Answer (score 1):

```
    ;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by PartNo order by DateAdded desc) as rn
    from PartsUsed
    )
    select *
    from x
    where x.BusNo = @busNo
    and x.PartNo in (select ID from @Usertable) 
    and x.rn = 1
```